# Linux Guest OS hostname change problems

Tags: linux, windows, vmware-player

I have redhat ES4 Linux guest os installed (windows xxp host).

I have changed the hostname in /etc/sysconfig/network from localhost:localdomain to another (FQDN) name. I have not altered anything in etc/hosts (still 127.0.0.1 localhost:localdomain locahost)

Then done system network restart and system config network.

However after this I can't open a terminal session .

Looks like my xterminal session is screwed up somewhere - but don't know how.

I've done a reboot and get the command line.

Thanks for your help

Comment: what actually happens when yo try to open a terminal session?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add this new hostname to your hosts file. If you don't, then anything that relies on hostname <--> IP lookups (a surprisingly large amount of X windows, sudo, etc.) will fail when trying *gethostbyname()*.

You can add another loopback entry in there, which is the right thing to do anyway so that 
foo.baz.bar.com (or whatever FQDN you named your host), has an entry like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
127.0.0.1 foo foo.baz.bar.com
```

Of course you can also join them all on one line as well.